# Java loop not looping when code is added to loop

Tags: java

Im confused as when i add code inside a loop it stops the looping (effectivly ending after the first round).

Code which is working fine

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(4096);
  while ((rs.next())) {
  System.err.println(rs.getRow());
  sb.append(rs.getString(1)).append(",");
  }
writeToCell(sheet,"P",row.getRowNum()+1,sb.toString());
```

Code which doesnt loop

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(4096);
    while ((rs.next())) {
    System.err.println(rs.getRow());
    String p=rs.getString(1);
    ArrayList<Parent> pscore = new ArrayList();
    pscore.add(new Parent(p));
    String Score= getSegment(pscore);
    sb.append(p).append("(").append(Score).append("),");
    }
writeToCell(sheet,"P",row.getRowNum()+1,sb.toString());
```

I cant figure out why it would loop in the top version and not the bottom version. No errors are thrown

Comment: Wait Wait Wait.. What is not working?? What's the output? What did you expected?

Comment: Maybe something happens to `rs` in the `getSegment()` method?

Comment: The code gets the first result from rs in the bottom loop, The top loop has all results from rs.

Comment: I dont get the exact error because you are giving too little info, but "ArrayList<Parent> pscore" is better to be declared outside the loop

Comment: Not quite - but the answer has helped me find the correct answer ! Thanks Keppil

Comment: You said no errors were thrown? ;)  (How about a debugger?)

Comment: have you written two loop one after another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that

```
pscore.add(new Parent(p));
String Score= getSegment(pscore);
```

performs a database query which replaces the `rs` which has finished before getSegment returns so the next call to `rs.next()` will be false.

To avoid this I would make sure that `rs` is a local variable instead of a field.

If this is the case, the best solution is likely to make the original SELECT a join between the tables so that is has all the information you need rather than performing a query per row.

Answer (score 0):

Keppils comment drew me towards the answer

"Maybe something happens to rs in the getSegment() method? "

Im not sure how to give any credit ive upvoted the comment but cant accept the comment as correct

The Parent Class uses a static variable for the database connection so when its defined it overridden the rs variable.